# what to do with a expired development profile

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

My Team Provisioning Certificate recently expired invaliding all the test versions of my apps on my phone. I have since updated it but the app still fails to open. Is there anything else I need to do to bring them back to life? I would ideally not want to reinstall new versions on my phone to preserve data etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the new, valid provisioning profile on the device.  Usually that is done through re-building and installing the app on the device. installing a new version over the existing one should preserve data, unless you have made Core Data changes but kept the same version.

If you are using a wildcard ID in your provisioning profile, you could get the existing app(s) to work by installing a new app using the new provisioning profile on the device.  Once the app (and provisioning profile) are installed on the device, all the old apps should work.